# How let vscode auto use cmake include path

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I have a cmake project, which use `find_package(OpenCV)` to find and include opencv lib and headers.

It work well to compiler and run. But the vscode can't automatic parse cmake config to get right include path.

The screenshot is [image]

After some research. I find some manually config like [Visual Studio Code: C++ include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122358/visual-studio-code-c-include-path)

My question is: Is the any why to let `vscode` automatic parse cmake `include_path`??

My English is poor. If I explain not clearly, please let me know. Thank you!

Update:

After do `CMake: configure`, it resolved.

Comment: "But the vscode can't automatic parse cmake config to get right include path." - There is no "cmake config" which contains include paths. These paths are obtained only when `CMakeLists.txt` is **processed** (not *parsed*, but *executed*, line by line). If VSCode doesn't process `CMakeLists.txt`, then you need to create a `compile_commands.json` file from CMake project. This file contains all compiler settings and it can be used by VSCode. [That answer] and its comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50360945/3440745) describes how to obtain such `.json` file.

Comment: Are you using the vscode-cmake-tools extension? When CMake is invoked through the extension, it should automatically add arguments to export compile commands. Apparantly though, compile_commands.json is not required for certain setups. See the [extension docs on setting up include-path intellisense](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/how-to.md#set-up-include-paths-for-c-intellisense).

Answer (score 1):

Crtl + shift + p

>Cmake configure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).